# IndexMatch across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have a sheet into which I need to pull specific data from another workbook which has in excess of 20 tabs all named by year.

I need to match three sets of criteria for it to accomplish this, so have created a concatenated column in all tabs, and in the main sheet which will be made up of the same data )all alphanumeric added as text).

I can do this from ONE sheet, but need to do it across many and would like it to be dynamic so I don't keep having to manage the formula every year.

Sheet one is called ADS, and sheet 2 is called NDTREQ, within the ADS file I have created a table called Years for the year names, but do not know how I can incorporate this into a dynamic formula.

This is the formula I have below in the cell within the ADS file is as below:

```
=IF(B16="","",INDEX([NDTREQ.xls]2018'!$G$1:$G$65536,MATCH(J16,[NDTREQ.xls]2018'!$A$1:$A$65536,FALSE),0))
```

How can I have this working dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the tab reference part of your formula dynamic, i.e. `[NDTREQ.xls]2018'`.

So instead of "hardcoding" the worksheet's year "2018" in your formula, it can be referred to a cell (in my example of your code I use cell: C5). The cell will contain the year (and explicit the worksheet tab) you want to use your formula at. 
I.e. changing the value in C5 from 2017 to 2018 will redirect the formula from worksheet tab 2017 to tab 2018.

So your formula should look something like this:

```
=IF(B16="","",INDEX(INDIRECT("[NDTREQ.xls]"&C5&"!"&"$G$1:$G$65536"),MATCH(J16,INDIRECT("[NDTREQ.xls]"&C5&"!"&"$A$1:$A$6553"),FALSE),0))
```

Explanation with a sample:

It's the `INDIRECT` function that allows to do this by a dynamic formula:

`INDIRECT("[NDTREQ.xls]"&C5&"!"&"B4:B7")`

- Where `[NDTREQ.xls]` is the file name,
- `"&C5&"!"` is the tab name in the file "NDTREQ",
- `&"B4:B7"` is the range in the index formula you want to return values in.

*Edit mark:*
I share two documents which I have worked with to give you an idea of what you can accomplish with the `INDIRECT`function in Excel. The file ADS is the "Main/Master" file which consumes data from the NDTREQ file.

Have the both worksheet in the same folder open at the same time. You should then get the result as the picture.
(If you want to have them at separate places you need to link the document with the path name). 
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4b86erzq6xj5l6/ADS.xls?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq1yhgm2zppyaf3/NDTREQ.xls?dl=0

Comment: I have typed the following but get a #REF error - doesn't seem to like the very first part of the formula.

=IF(B16="","",INDEX(SUM(INDIRECT("[NDTREQ.xls]"&Support!A6:A41&"!"&"$G:$G")),MATCH(J16,SUM(INDIRECT("[NDTREQ.xls]"&Support!A6:A41&"!"&"'!$A:$A")),FALSE),0))

Support is a Tab in the main workbook where I need the source data copied into.  I also have removed the path to the data source file as it is now open due to the INDIRECT requirement.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Tried your formula above, but I still get the REF error.

Comment: I have edit my answer, hopefully it can give you the help you need to modify it for your needs.

Comment: I notice some strange things in your formula:
First I apologies for confusing you with the sum example. SUM shouldn't be a part of your formula.
Second, `Support!A6:A41....` will not work. This part of the code should be 1 cell (since a there can only be 1 tab at the time which you return values from). This cell contains the name of the worksheet you want to return values from.

Comment: Wiz, in effect this means I need to add all tabs individually, as the data could be in any one of the 20 tabs in the NDTREQ worksheet?  As the indirect formula works from a single reference cell for the tab, and won't work from a range?  am I right?

Comment: Think I have a way of doing this do I don't need to add the formulae above (which now works - thanks for that) for each tab in.  I can put all the formulae in a row for each tab (including ones which don't exist yet (years 2000 - 2050 for example), us the IFERROR function and then in the cell where I need to display the data use a formula to find the one cell which isn't blank, and if they are all blank add a condition which returns text telling the user what to do.

Comment: WIZ, your explanation above, plus some playing from me sorted the issue - thanks massively.

Comment: Yes you're right about the individually tabs. INDIRECT assumes you have a singe reference value. (You could use an array but you need to get the result from the array to one value).
I'm impressed by your way to solve it. Great work and effort by you. I'm only glad I could contribute in some minor way :). Take care.